# Problem with LoadManager

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am struggling to figure out why this codes work using the Honeycomb SDK but fails when using the compatibility library. Specifically, `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this)`, works with the Honeycomb SDK but when using the Compatibility library the parameters appear to be different and I am not sure what to do.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        /*
        *
        * The following works fine when using: 
        * import android.app.LoaderManager;
        * import android.content.CursorLoader;
        * import android.content.Loader;
        *
        * but fails when using (requires different parameters)
        * import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
        * import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
        * import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
        *
        */

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


    }    

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was mistaken, it's still `getLoaderManager()` not `getSupportLoaderManager()`.

The arguments are the same as Honeycomb and it looks like you have it right in your code.  Is Eclipse complaining about it taking different params?

Comment: like this? getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);